# How to disable Google Experiments Variant via URL

Tags: google-experiments

Is it possible to disable Google Experiments for debugging adding manually a variable to the Url address in the browser?

Like for example: debug=1

> http://www.example.net/?var=kekiql&fo=fiusispn**&debug=1**